# Как скопировать файлы с сервера на сервер

Tags: debian, centos

Нужно скопировать файлы с сервера на centos на сервер с debian? ssh есть на debian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть статейка, вытекающая из вашего вопроса, где вы упомянули SSH. -> [here](http://wiki.enchtex.info/tools/console/scp)

Иные способы, может, кто еще подскажет, разве что посмотрите совет по использованию [rsync](http://wiki.enchtex.info/tools/console/rsync) оттуда же

Comment: Проблема уже решена, спасибо. Ваш Ответ тоже верный )

Answer (score 1):

ну если есть ssh, то проще всего через scp

```
scp /path_/filename_ user@server_centos:filename_
```

ну как-то так.